# Implied globals are not caught as linter errors

Tags: javascript, jshint

When I create a new file in a directory, `jshint` doesn't catch "implied globals" error. There's no such issue with the other files in the directory.

My file has just one line

```
console.log(hohoho);
```

and here's the linter output

```
$ jshint --verbose --show-non-errors foo.js

foo.js :
  Implied globals:
    hohoho: 1
```

For the other files I see a problem:

```
$ jshint --verbose asset.js
asset.js: line 6, col 13, 'hohoho' is not defined. (W117)

2 errors
```

My `.jshintrc` doesn't mention any explicit files. Any ideas?

Comment: This github issue may help: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/668/

Comment: @Jacques I have the opposite of that issue, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to add a `'use strict';` line at the top of the file to catch the globals issue.